# JSON schema validator using Python

Tags: python, json, validation, python-2.7, jsonschema

I have written JSON validator in python using **jsonschema** module.
Its not validating the schema correctly. I am also using web based tool, **http://jsonschemalint.com/** for validating.

I wanted to exactly have some thing similar.  I am putting my code here please point out the things that I am mising.

```
from jsonschema import validate
import json

class jsonSchemaValidator(object):
    def __init__(self, schema_file):
        self.__schema_file = open(schema_file)
        self.__json_schema_obj = json.load(self.__schema_file)

    def validate(self, json_file):
        json_data_obj = json.load(open(json_file))

        try:
            validate(json_data_obj, self.__json_schema_obj)
            print 'The JSON is follows the schema'
        except Exception, extraInfo:
            print str(extraInfo)





data_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\LT-BPant\\Desktop\\Del\\Schema\\new schema\\sample_output\\'
schema_path = 'C:\\Users\\LT-BPant\\Desktop\\Del\\Schema\\new schema\\'
def main():
    json_file = data_file_path  + 'report.json'
    schema = schema_path+ 'report_new.schema'
    obj = jsonSchemaValidator(schema)
    obj.validate(json_file)

main()
```

I have manually modified the json data but still I am getting  `JSON DATA follows the schema` as oputput whereas the web based tool is correctly showing the difference.

Comment: It would be useful if you posted the schema, and a sample JSON that is not validating with that schema...

Comment: You are setting the JSON file path to the `schema` variable, and the schema file path to the `json_file` variable. Shouldn't this be the other way round?

Comment: @dnll I didnot get you what are you saying?